# jQuery click not firing on labels in div

Tags: jquery, html, click, label, children

I have the following html-code:

```
    <input type="text" size="30" id="county" class="auto_input" autocomplete="off" />
    <div id="l_county" class="autocomplete"></div>
```

along with jQuery getting data from an API (it's an address autocomplete form)
When you've written something in the text field, a list of counties/streets/cities/zipcodes (depending on textfield) pops out underneath the text field, html looking like this:

```
    <div id="l_county" class="autocomplete" style="display: block;">
    <label id="s_county" class="suggestion">
    Värmland
    </label>
    <label id="s_county" class="suggestion">
    Västerbotten
    </label>
    </div>
```

I can't get jQuery to fire a click-event on the labels.
I've tried;

```
    $('.suggestion').on('click', ...
    $('.autocomplete').children().on('click', ...
    $('.autocomplete > label').on('click', ....
```

And a few others I can't recall. Nothing works. But

```
    $('.autocomplete').on('click', ...
```

works great, but that doesn't help much since I need the data from the s. I'm desperate for help, I'm working past deadline due to complications from another part, and this ridiculous problem keeps me from progressing.

**Edit:**
I found the issue. It was a ridiculous miss on my part.

```
    $('body').on('click', '.suggestion', function() {});
```

That works. The issue was that the labels were dynamically generated via .append()
Well this was a waste of your time. My apologies, and thank you, this did indirectly make me figure it out.

Comment: Your labels have same id and it's bad. And for click event I think you can use `jQuery(label.suggestion).click(function(){jQuery(this).dosomething...});`

Comment: May this work  $('.autocomplete').find("label").on('click', ...

Comment: Aw shit, didn't think about the ID thing. Yeah, that's bad. Will fix. Trying your suggestions, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could look Ingo the autocomplete API and search for the method that adds the childs to the box. There you implement your onClick-Listener.
But I Bad a similar problem my own, and I've found a solution. I'll look for it and post it here ;)

Comment: The API only returns pure data in JSON format. There is an .autocomplete feature of jQuery UI but I didn't get that to work when I tried a while ago. This has nothing to do with the API itself, it's just that I can't seem to get to the labels inside the div :/

Answer (score 0):

Try the click event of your Label like below.... it will help you..

```
$("[id=s_county]").live('click', function () {
      alert(this.innerHTML);
  });
```

Fiddle Link :  http://jsfiddle.net/RYh7U/50/

Answer (score 0):

> You might trying to get element before they get created. use :`$(document).ready(function(){ $('.suggestion').on('click', ...);
>       $('.autocomplete').children().on('click', ...);
>       $('.autocomplete > label').on('click', ...); });`